# Usage of "beyond"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

I wrote:

> However, good deeds are beyond wealth.

I mean that good deeds (**generosity**) can be done even without  money and having  money isn't a requisite.

Did I use "beyond" correctly?

---

**Update:** I know my sentence is short and vague. But I meant: "to be generous you shouldn't necessarily have a lot of money", I should have used **generosity**.

Comment: Well, if you meant to say that good deeds are more important than wealth, then yes, you used it correctly.

Comment: It's not really an idiomatic way to use *beyond*, though.  If I read that, I would think it meant that good deeds are *better* than wealth or something.  I think what you mean is something more like "good deeds *don't require* wealth."

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in one of the comments, *beyond* as used in your example implies *'more important than'*, or perhaps, *'you can't place a monetary value on good deeds'*.

Or to rephrase your example:

> However, good deeds are more important than wealth.

If however, you are trying to get across the point that money isn't a requisite to performing a good deed, then it doesn't quite work. Perhaps, something along the lines of

> However, good deeds **cost nothing**.

...might get the point across more clearly.

Comment: Yes. My sentence is ambiguous and short. But I meant: "to be generous you shouldn't necessarily have a lot of money"

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't feel quite right to compare "good deeds" to "wealth" -- it's ["apples to oranges"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/compare+apples+and+oranges) .  If anything you want to compare two abstract concepts, like "health vs. wealth" or "love vs. wealth" or "generosity vs. wealth".   Or, alternately, something like: "Good deeds are more important than hard cash".

"Beyond" is fine when used in the proper context, but you probably want to say "go beyond" instead.  Again, I have trouble relating "good deeds" directly to "wealth", so something like:

> "Acts of simple kindness go beyond the mere accumulation of *things*"

Or more succinctly:

> "Good deeds far surpass gold"

or even better:

> "Good deeds are pure gold"

But there are already many aphorisms that express this feeling:

> "And in the end / The love you take is equal to the love you make" - The Beatles
>
> "Kindness is the language which the deaf can hear and the blind can see." -Mark Twain
>
> "The best way to find yourself is to lose yourself in the service of others." - Mahatma Gandhi

Comment: You are right, I tried to do a literal translation of a Persian learner to translate his sentence back to English. I explained a bit more in my question. I meant **generosity**, though still the sentence could be vauge.

Comment: @Ahmad I'm sure we have the same *thoughts* in both languages, we just *express* them differently.   Plus, when writing a maxim or other short statement of moral value, you have to consider the flow and rhythm of the words to make them sound pleasing -- which means you have to pick certain words that both work in that language, and which fit the music.  :)